# VBA rename sheets based on Inputbox cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to rename sheets based on the same cell within each sheet. When i run the macro rather than having the cell predefined I would like to use an input box to define what cell the sheets are to be named after. This is what I have so far- currently it works for only cell C8.

```
Sub RenameSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    If Len(ws.Range("C8")) > 0 Then
        ws.Name = ws.Range("C8").Value
    End If 
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws.Name <> ws.Range("C8").Value Then
        MsgBox ws.Name & " Was Not renamed, the suggested name was invalid"
    End If
Next 
End Sub
```

I think this code would help but I cannot get it to run

```
Set CellID = Application.InputBox("Cell reference to label sheets", Type:=8)
```

Anyone have help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following changes.

Also it would be a good idea to activate the current sheet so the user always automatically selects a cell on the correct sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RenameSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        ws.Activate 'so we automatically are on the correct sheet to select a range

        Dim CellID As Range
        Set CellID = Application.InputBox("Cell reference to label sheets", Type:=8)

        If CellID.Count > 1 Then 'check how many cells were selected
            MsgBox "Please select only one cell!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Len(CellID.Value) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Name = CellID.Value
            'catch the error
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox ws.Name & " Was Not renamed, the suggested name was invalid"
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            MsgBox ws.Name & " Was Not renamed, the suggested name was empty"
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

---

Alternative to select the address once and use the same address on every worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RenameSheet()
    Dim CellID As Range
    Set CellID = Application.InputBox("Cell reference to label sheets", Type:=8)

    If CellID.Count > 1 Then 'check how many cells were selected
        MsgBox "Please select only one cell!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim NameAddress As String
    NameAddress = CellID.Address(External:=False)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Len(ws.Range(NameAddress).Value) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            ws.Name = ws.Range(NameAddress).Value
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox ws.Name & " Was Not renamed, the suggested name was invalid"
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            MsgBox ws.Name & " Was Not renamed, the suggested name was empty"
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help - I am very new to VBA and am self taught. Is there away that the input cell range is applied to all sheets rather than having to do so for each sheet. So if A3 is selected then all sheets are named on the value contained within A3 of the respective sheet.

Comment: @Mholyoake See my edit. I added the alternative solution, so you can investigate the difference. If this solved your question please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Sub RenameSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, CellID As Range
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set CellID = Application.InputBox("Cell reference to label sheets", Type:=8)
        Set CellID = ws.Cells(CellID.Row, CellID.Column)
        On Error Resume Next
        ws.Name = CellID
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ws.Name <> CellID.Value Then
            MsgBox ws.Name & " Was Not renamed, the suggested name was invalid"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code will set your range twice, because the inputbox assumes `ActiveSheet`, as there's no way to assign the worksheet name to your input range without typing it out.

Therefore, once you type in the cell address, it will utilize the `.Row` and `.Column` properties of the inputrange of the activesheet, while assigning them to the correct worksheet since we didn't qualify the worksheet in `CellID.Row` and `CellID.Column`.